# Error: React Hook "useEffect" is called conditionally. React Hooks must be called in the exact same order in every component render

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js

```
import { setCookies, removeCookies } from "cookies-next";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import { useEffect } from "react";
const { URL } = process.env;

export const getServerSideProps = async (context) => {
  const userAuthToken = context.req.cookies["authToken"];
  const data = {
    authToken: userAuthToken,
  };
  const requestJSON = JSON.stringify(data);
  const response = await fetch(URL + "api/userFetch", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    body: requestJSON,
  });
  const responseData = await response.json();
  return {
    props: { datas: responseData },
  };
};

const Home = ({ datas }) => {
  const router = useRouter();
  if (datas[0].error == true) {
    useEffect(() => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        router.push("/");
      }, 3000);
    }, []);
    removeCookies("authToken");
    return <h1>Something Went Wrong</h1>;
  } else {
    return <h1>Welcome To Home{datas[0].error}</h1>;
  }
};

export default Home;
```

This code is running fine on development server but when I try to build this code in production I get this error **
./pages/Home.js
28:5  Error: React Hook "useEffect" is called conditionally. React Hooks must be called in the exact same order in every component render. Did you accidentally call a React Hook after an early return?**

I tried everything I could but can't fix the error

Comment: I'm not sure what we can add to the error message. You cannot use a hook inside a condition within the component. It needs to be called every render or React cannot track it properly.

Comment: How can I fix this code ?

Answer (score 2):

Just do *exactly what the error is telling you*.  Move the `useEffect` call out of the conditional block.  You can still conditionally perform the operation *within the hook*.  For example:

```
const Home = ({ datas }) => {
  const router = useRouter();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (datas[0].error == true) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        router.push("/");
      }, 3000);
    }
  }, []);

  if (datas[0].error == true) {
    removeCookies("authToken");
    return <h1>Something Went Wrong</h1>;
  } else {
    return <h1>Welcome To Home{datas[0].error}</h1>;
  }
};
```

Specifically, as the error states, the same hooks must always be called on every render.  (I don't know enough under the hood of React to describe why that's the case, it just seems necessary for stability/consistency/etc.)  But the operation being performed by the hook in this case can still be effectively a no-op if the intended condition is not met.

Comment: This fixed my error, thank you so much